# Bizarre IE bug with excel plugin

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This bug in our legacy app is blowing my mind. I don't even know how to describe it to google to search for good help.  This is all in Internet Explorer as this older app doesn't support anything else.

- I click on the menu (which is in a different frame of a frameset from the main content frame) to load the page.
- On the page is a link to download an excel spreadsheet in a separate window with excel (MIME type is application/vnd.ms-excel).
- While the link does work, excel issues TWO requests to our servlet without passing the JSESSIONID, which is odd, but the requests don't seem to matter if we just bail out of the request and return nonsense.  The file was already downloaded.
- BUT WAIT, it gets weirder. If you hit the link TWICE without closing excel, and then try to click anything in the menu frame, the javascript runs, the servlet responds (I can see the right HTML returned in the network tab), but the main content window DOES NOT CHANGE.  Clicking something in the main content window DOES work (there's a popup window button).

There are no javascript errors in the console.  If I close excel the tab remains unresponsive, but the problem does not affect OTHER browser tabs.  Note that it's so dead that clicking the refresh button on the browser does nothing.  And yet...the debugger shows js does run, and the main window popup does respond.

I'm mostly confident that this is something to do with the excel.  Is there a known bug or something?

Comment: People still using Internet Explorer is blowing my mind ;) I don't know of such a bug tho. Maybe it is your Javascript going crazy on the background. (Especially because the main content window doesn't change after doing the same thing twice)

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ - It's a legacy app that everyone says will be re-written next year...and then it's next year....and then the next.  There's always higher priorities.  Any thoughts on workaround?

Comment: First of all, I want to suggest you to upgrade to IE 11 as other older versions are out of support. We don't know that which exact code your app is using so we cannot make any guess about the issue. if possible than try to provide some sample code with detailed steps which can produce the issue. We can try to reproduce it on our side and try to find any possible solution or a work around for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Entropy that is a really difficult situation, especially from an IT perspective. I don't know how close you/your team is towards the business in the organization, but I would strongly advise that somebody stands up and shouts that the time has come to migrate. I am no legacy expert, but as Deepak-MSFT states, it is indeed a must to even just upgrade to IE 11. And yes, we need some code example to see where the issue might be.